# How to use UIElement.Effect to color the element somewhat blue?

Tags: wpf, effects

Is there an easy way to use `UIElement.Effect` in WPF to shift the color of my element, as if it had a blue semi-transparent overlay on top of it?

I'm sure there are lots of other ways of achieving the look I'm after; there's no need to suggest those. I'd like to know how to use `UIElement.Effect` specifically, rather than an alternative technique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is [ColorToneEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.media.effects.colortoneeffect%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) from Expression Blend of any use?

For example:

```
<Button Content="This is a test" Height="Auto">
    <Button.Effect>
        <ee:ColorToneEffect DarkColor="AliceBlue" LightColor="AliceBlue"/>
    </Button.Effect>
</Button>
```

Comment: It sounds about right. Not entirely sure about that DLL: will I have to include it with my application?

Comment: Yes you would.  Luckily I don't think you need to buy Blend, you can just download the SDK. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801

Comment: Currently, it is available as Nuget package named Microsoft.SDK.Expression.Blend and can be included as `xmlns:ee="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/effects"`